# Is there any way to make a UNIQUE index case insensitive in Mysql 5.1.x ?

Tags: mysql, unique-index

If so - What must change in this table ?

```
CREATE TABLE  contestants 
( 
  idContestants  int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  idEvent        int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  ContestantName  varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idContestants),
  UNIQUE KEY Index_UniqueName (idEvent,ContestantName),
)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What does 'case instinctive' mean?

Comment: Do you mean case insensitive?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you mean case sensitive then:

```
ALTER TABLE `contestants` CHANGE `ContestantName` `ContestantName` VARCHAR( 50 )
CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

If you mean case insensitive then:

```
ALTER TABLE `contestants` CHANGE `ContestantName` `ContestantName` VARCHAR( 50 )
CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

For table level do (for case insensitive):

```
ALTER TABLE `contestants` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci
```

Note that table level only affects new columns.

For database level do (for case insensitive):

```
ALTER DATABASE `database_name` CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci
```

Note that database level only affect new tables.

Comment: It is important to note that this is a COLUMN level collation, initially I read this too quickly and thought it was a TABLE level collation which didn't work for me.

Comment: @ScottJungwirth I added info about changing it at table and database level.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use a case-insensitive collation on the columns involved.

[MySQL Manual :: Column Character Set and Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-column.html)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Mysql 5.5

```sql
ALTER TABLE `contestants` MODIFY
`ContestantName` VARCHAR(50) 
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_bin;
```