# Doctrine ORM unique string is not case sensitive

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I got an Entity with field like that:

```
/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;
```

But if i try to fix a typo in name from "test" to "Test" i got an error that this name is already taken! Any idea why is that happening? Is an unique index case insenstive?

Comment: It's likely a problem with the database. Here's a question for mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888279/is-there-any-way-to-make-a-unique-index-case-insensitive-in-mysql-5-1-x

Comment: There is another question about this case i think:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448825/sql-unique-varchar-case-sensitivity-question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is because you have utf8_general_ci collation note the **_ci** which means **case-insensitive**, in turn that means that database treats "Test", "test", "TEst" etc. identically.

You will have to change column collation in the database manually to utf8_bin, or to utf8_xxx_**cs** (where xxx is language name) if you happen to have one for the needed language.

From Doctrine ORM FAQ:

> 4.1.1. How do I set the charset and collation for MySQL tables?
>
> You can’t set these values inside the annotations, yml or xml mapping
>   files. To make a database work with the default charset and collation
>   you should configure MySQL to use it as default charset, or create the
>   database with charset and collation details. This way they get
>   inherited to all newly created database tables and columns.

Comment: I found a PR on github https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/245 so at least someone working on it.